# Invertibility of laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set with smooth boundary. How to prove the invertibility of $$- \triangle:H^2_0(\Omega) \to L²(\Omega) $$

The injectivity is easy. But how to prove surjectivity without the use of weak notion of solution (when the domain becomes $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and this can be easily found in books)?

Comment: Are you sure it is $H_0^2$?

Comment: yes. @Tomás. This article has a citation to the result: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue

Comment: I think there is an mistake there. You have to change $H_0^2$ by $H_0^1$. If not you are saying that every solution of the Dirichlet problem has null derivative in the boundary of $\Omega$. This is not true as you can easily see contructing one dimensional examples.

Comment: @Tomas That would not fix things, because the inverse operator (convolution with $|x|^{2-n}$) converts $L^2$ functions into $H^2$ functions.

Comment: @5PM, so is it better to consider $H_0^1\cap H^2$? I think in this case we have a homeomorphism $L^2\rightarrow H_0^1\cap H^2$.

Comment: You are right, @Tomás.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator $$- \triangle:H^1_0(\Omega) \to L²(\Omega) $$
is "surjective" in the weak sense (as a direct use of Riesz representation theorem).

Then you can use regularity theorems to prove that, in fact, this weak solution is in $H^2(\Omega)$. A good reference to a  result like this is the Brezis book  "functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDE". See theorem 9.25 and note that a $C^2$ domain $\Omega$ is required. So your result is valid from $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega) $ to $L²(\Omega) $.